# python OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError glGenBuffers

Tags: python, opengl

when I run [this code](https://code.google.com/p/deep-learning-obj-recog/source/checkout) test_rbm.py in the directory which name is python-deepnets.

I got error.

`OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glGenBuffers, check for bool(glGenBuffers) before calling`

and after google,

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAAT2aSMyqrGBFydWSSaZkRsR_jtbrh%2Biy9j1Zgjv-MFX95nB1g%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=pyopengl-users

they say:

> Your code is attempting to call OpenGL-context requiring code without an
>   OpenGL context (window).  Do the glGenBuffer and similar calls within a
>   draw callback of your windowing system (e.g. GLUT).  You may also need to
>   verify that your machine has a reasonably recent video card that supports
>   modern OpenGL (but most do these days).

but I don't really understand the meaning.

is that mean I don't have the VGA card so I can't excuse the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you told us which Python OpenGL library you are using and what platform and libraries the program is running on.

OpenGL draws 3D graphics. It can't draw anything without a window and an OpenGL-capable context. (Equivalent to a MS Windows DC, X11 drawable, MacOS view.) And on many but not all graphical platforms, the only place you can draw without crashing is in the designated paint / drawRect / update event handler. Try to do anything in OpenGL without all these, and your program crashes.